# angular ui boostrap datepicker show years first

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I need to show year first at angular ui boostrap datepicker because user needs to select day of birth and it is difficult to figure out there it needs to select on month above to select month, than select on year above to select year.
This is what I tried:

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    minMode: 'year',
    maxMode:'day'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `ui.bootstrap 0.13.4`, you need to set it as attribute in the `datepicker` element or you need configure `datepickerConfig` to apply globally. 
While defining as an attribute write like this:

```
datepicker-mode="'year'"
```

Don't forget to use single quote inside the double quotes(or vice versa).

See the updated plunk after defining the attribute http://plnkr.co/edit/xNg244qbfgTnAcginH43?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Working Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/KAVPzZOOJPpKbEyio1Yg?p=preview

This is what you want: `datepickerMode: 'year'`.

```
$scope.options = {
  datepickerMode: 'year'
};
```

Comment: Yes, it will let you do that.  Check the Plunk.

Comment: It is not working with angular 1.3.9 and boostrap ui 0.13.4 .Here is the plank:  http://plnkr.co/edit/FJqQ9iMOi6j4VayUIH7h?p=preview